# When to call job.getJobID()?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a hadoop program which is running successfully. I need to extract jobID from it. I am using following code to do that:

```
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        conf.addResource(new Path("../conf/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("../conf/mapred-site.xml"));

        conf.addResource(new Path("../conf/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));


        Job job = new Job(conf,"CloudViTra2.0_Transcoder - Job1");



        job.setJarByClass(VideoTranscoder.class);   
        job.setMapperClass(First_Mapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(First_Reducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);


        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("../thesis_uploads/input/"+getFileName[0]+".txt"));


        Path output = new Path("../thesis_uploads/output_"+fileName+"/");


        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
        currentJob = job.getJobID().toString();
```

The problem here is that this program waits until the job is done. I need the jobID while execution. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the job client api for this refer [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html)

Use jobstatus[].getAllJobs() and jobstatus[].jobsToComplete() to get the jobIds of the current running job.

Find below a psuedo code :

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(new Path(hadoopConfPath + "core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path(hadoopConfPath + "hdfs-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path(hadoopConfPath + "mapred-site.xml"));

    InetSocketAddress jobtracker = new InetSocketAddress(jobTrackerHost, jobTrackerPort);
    JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(jobtracker, conf);
    jobClient.setConf(conf);

    JobStatus[] jobs = jobClient.getAllJobs();


    for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
        JobStatus js = jobs[i];
        JobID job1 = js.getJobID();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: in JobTrackerHost will come IP of my VM? and port is 50030? Right?